# Hierarchical clustering with mixed type data - what distance/similarity to use?

Tags: clustering, similarities, distance-functions, mixed-type-data, gower-similarity

In my dataset we have both continuous and naturally discrete variables. I want to know whether we can do hierarchical clustering using both type of variables. And if yes, what distance measure is appropriate?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: @rolando2: I'm using R (hclus package).

Comment: Is there a reason for using hierarchical clustering?

Comment: Na. I just asking this question for the sake of my knowledge. Can we do hierarchical when we have mixed data type. If yes, then why? If no, then why?

Comment: @user4278 Well, what's your goal *in fine*? Are you looking to identify clusters (of individuals)?

Comment: Yes. I've this data & I want to cluster the individuals based on certain vars. Now the vars I'm using are mixed, i.e. some vars are discrete while other continuous.So my question is could I have used hierarchical method using R?

Comment: Yes it is integrated in Cluster package in R and you need to use the daisy () function to calculate the dissimilarity matrix.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

One way is to use **Gower similarity coefficient** which is a composite measure$^1$; it takes quantitative (such as rating scale), binary (such as present/absent) and nominal (such as worker/teacher/clerk) variables. Later Podani$^2$ added an option to take ordinal variables as well.

The coefficient is easily understood even without a formula; you compute the similarity value between the individuals by each variable, taking the type of the variable into account, and then average across all the variables. Usually, a program calculating Gower will allow you to weight variables, that is, their contribution, to the composite formula. However, proper weighting of variables of *different* type is a [problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74253/3277), no clear-cut guidelines exist, which makes Gower or other "composite" indices of proximity pull ones face.

The facets of Gower similarity ($GS$):

- When all variables are quantitative (interval) then the coefficient is the range-normalized **Manhattan distance** converted into similarity. Because of the normalization variables of different units may be safely used. You should not, however, forget about outliers. (You might also decide to normalize by another measure of spread than range.) Because of the said normalization by a statistic, such as range, which is sensitive to the composition of individuals in the dataset Gower similarity between some two individuals may change its value if you remove or add some other individuals in the data.
- When all variables are ordinal, then they are first ranked, and then Manhattan is computed, as above with quantitative variables, but with the special adjustment for ties.
- When all variables are binary (with an asymmetric significance of categories: "present" vs "absent" attribute) then the coefficient is the **Jaccard** matching coefficient (this coefficient treats when both individuals lack the attribute as neither match nor mismatch).
- When all variables are nominal (also including here dichotomous with symmetric significance: "this" vs "that") then the coefficient is the **Dice** matching coefficient that you obtain from your nominal variables if recode them into dummy variables (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55802/3277) for more).

(It is easy to extend the list of types. For example, one could add a summand for count variables, using normalized chi-squared distance converted to similarity.)

The coefficient ranges between 0 and 1.

"**Gower distance**". Without ordinal variables present (i.e. w/o using the Podani's option) $\sqrt{1-GS}$ behaves as Euclidean distance, it fully supports euclidean space. But $1-GS$ is only metric (supports triangular inequality), not Euclidean. With ordinal variables present (using the Podani's option) $\sqrt{1-GS}$ is only metric, not Euclidean; and $1-GS$ isn't metric at all. [See also](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22213/3277).

With euclidean distances (distances supporting Euclidean space), virtually any classic clustering technique will do. Including [K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81494/3277) (if your K-means program can process distance matrices, of course) and including Ward's, centroid, median methods of [Hierarchical clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/217742/3277). Using K-means or other those methods based on Euclidean distance with non-euclidean still metric distance is *heuristically* admissible, perhaps. With non-metric distances, no such methods may be used.

The previous paragraph talks about if K-means or Ward's or such clustering is legal or not with Gower distance *mathematically* (geometrically). From the *measurement-scale* ("psychometric") point of view one should not compute mean or euclidean-distance deviation from it in any categorical (nominal, binary, as well as ordinal) data; therefore from *this* stance you just may not process Gower coefficient by K-means, Ward etc. This viewpoint warns that even if a Euclidean space is present it may be granulated, not smooth ([see related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16335/3277)).

If you want all the formulae and additional info on Gower similarity / distance, please read the description of my SPSS macro `!KO_gower`; it's in the Word document found in collection "Various proximities" on my web-page.

---

$^1$ Gower J. C. A general coefficient of similarity and some of its properties // Biometrics, 1971, 27, 857-872

$^2$ Podani, J. Extending Gower’s general coefficient of similarity to ordinal characters // Taxon, 1999, 48, 331-340

Comment: Thanks ttnphns! Can you please tell me is "Gower similarity coefficient" is integrated in hclus package in R? Is there any package in R that has this functionality.

Comment: I'm not R user so don't know, and don't think you'll find it in hclus. But if you Google "Gower similarity R" you are sure to find what you need!

Comment: user4278, Just in case you don't shun SPSS, I have a macro for Gower similarity on my web-page. It accepts weighting and missing data.

Comment: @user4278 About R specifically, start here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Environmetrics.html

Comment: @ttnphns: Thanks you! I've visited you website & it is a great resource for SPSS. But unfortunately I don't use SPSS too much. But I'll surely use it if I don't get anything in R.@chl: Thank you! But it's a huge list. I read somewhere that Daisy, in cluster package, has functionality of Gower similarity.

Comment: You've made it clear that the Gower coefficient creates similarities when *all* variables are the same type. Does it also create similarities for mixtures of distributions as the OP stated, e.g., between "quantitative" and "nominal" variables?

Comment: @DJohnson, You misunderstood my "when all variables are the same type". By this phrase, I described _what of well-known other coefficients Gower coefficient becomes equal to_ - when it happens that all variables are of the same - specifically this or that - type. For example, with all variables binary, Gower actually "degenerates" into Jaccard. Gower coefficient is for mixed type variables. It can be of course used also with all same type variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "behaves as Euclidean distance"? As the Gower distance only takes values $\in[0,1]$, it does not share the scaling property with the Euclidean distance, i.e. when all values are doubled the Gower distance does not change, but the Euclidean distance doubles.

Comment: @cdalitz, the text says what I meant. It is _geometrically_ a Euclidean distance: the corresponding scalar product matrix is positive semidefinite. So it spans (some region of) Euclidean space, = the distances converge in Euclidean space (see nonconvergence on Fig 1 [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69206/3277)). The scaling property is irrelevant here, in the context discussed. For example, chord distance defined on a unit circle is bounded, but it is a true euclidean distance.

Comment: @ttnphns Can you please elaborate what the "corresponding scalar product" should be? AFAIK, for a metric feature vector, the Gower distance is identical to the scaled Manhatten distance, and the Manhatten distance does not fulfil the parallelogram equality, from which it follows that there is no "corresponding scalar product".

Comment: @cdalitz, I thought that you visited the linked anwser (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22213/3277). It explains that one should convert the distance matrix at hand to a Gram matrix via double centering. If the obtained matrix has no negative eigenvalues this means the distance matrix supports Euclidean space, i.e. the distances are geometrically euclidean ones. Now, sqrt(1-Gower) is _always_ such euclidean (without ordinal data used): it is therefore a (bounded in 0-1 range version of the) euclidean distance de facto. Remember I'm speaking of sqrt(1-Gower), not 1-Gower.

Answer (score 20):

If you have stumbled upon this question and are wondering what package to download for using **Gower metric in R**, the `cluster` package  has a function named [daisy()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/cluster/html/daisy.html), which by default uses Gower's metric whenever mixed types of variables are used. Or you can manually set it to use Gower's metric.

```
daisy(x, metric = c("euclidean", "manhattan", "gower"),
      stand = FALSE, type = list(), weights = rep.int(1, p))
```

Comment: Further to [Zhubarb's answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/146452/87503), if you want the Gower distances between all pairs from *two* data sets, then see the R package `StatMatch`.