# Clustering variables of mixed types in R

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, mixed-type-data

I need to analyse questionnaire survey data with mixed data types (nominal, ordinal, continuous). I want to cluster the variables. So far I only have dead ends.

- I know I can use daisy in the cluster package to cluster the cases, but I want to cluster the variables.
- lots of cluster procedures like ICLUST can cluster variables but they don't allow nominal data types.

The only thing I can think of is to split up the categorial variables into binary dummy variables, standardise everything, and then apply ICLUST.

Comment: Use [Gower measure](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/3277). About measures nominal data, read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55802/3277). For hierarchical and some other methods of clustering, it makes no difference whether you cluster individuals or attributes.

Answer (score -1):

The R package polLCA can handle all different datatypes almost seamlessly via latent cluster analysis.

Comment: Can you say more about this package, & latent cluster analysis? How would they help resolve the OP's problem?