# Hierarchical clustering with categorical variables - what distance/similarity to use in R?

Tags: clustering

I have only categorical variables in my database.

What distance/similarity to use?

I´m using the function simil() (library(proxy) in R.

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting your categorical variables into sets of dummy variables and then use the Jaccard index as the distance measure.

There is a more detailed explanation here: [What is the optimal distance function for individuals when attributes are nominal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55798/what-is-the-optimal-distance-function-for-individuals-when-attributes-are-nomina)

Comment: Thank you for the link to an answer of mine. However, I may notice that the answer recommended Dice rather than Jaccard for categorical (and hence dummy) attributes.