# With categorical data, can there be clusters without the variables being related?

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, independence

When trying to explain cluster analyses, it is common for people to misunderstand the process as being related to whether the variables are correlated.  One way to get people past that confusion is a plot like this:

[image]

This clearly displays the difference between the question of whether there are clusters and the question of whether the variables are related.  However, this only illustrates the distinction for continuous data.  I'm having trouble thinking of an analog with categorical data:

```r
ID  property.A  property.B
1   yes         yes
2   yes         yes
3   yes         yes
4   yes         yes
5   no          no
6   no          no
7   no          no
8   no          no
```

We can see that there are two clear clusters: people with both property A and B, and those with neither.  However, if we look at the variables (e.g., with a chi-squared test), they are clearly related:

```r
tab
#      B
# A     yes no
#   yes   4  0
#   no    0  4
chisq.test(tab)
# X-squared = 4.5, df = 1, p-value = 0.03389
```

I find I am at a loss for how to construct an example with categorical data that is analogous to the one with continuous data above.  Is it even possible to have clusters in purely categorical data without the variables being related as well?  What if the variables have more than two levels, or as you have larger numbers of variables?  If the clustering of observations does necessarily entail relationships between the variables and vice versa, does that imply that clustering is not really worth doing when you only have categorical data (i.e., should you just analyze the variables instead)?

---

*Update:* I left a lot out of the original question because I wanted to just focus on the idea that a simple example could be created that would be immediately intuitive even to someone who was largely unfamiliar with cluster analyses.  However, I recognize that a lot of clustering is contingent on choices of distances and algorithms, etc.  It may help if I specify more.

I recognize that Pearson's correlation is really only appropriate for continuous data.  For the categorical data, we could think of a chi-squared test (for a two-way contingency table) or a log-linear model (for multi-way contingency tables) as a way to assess the independence of the categorical variables.

For an algorithm, we could imagine using k-medoids / PAM, which can be applied to both the continuous situation and the categorical data.  (Note that, part of the intention behind the continuous example is that any reasonable clustering algorithm should be able to detect those clusters, and if not, a more extreme example should be possible to construct.)

Regarding the conception of distance, I assumed Euclidean for the continuous example, because it would be the most basic for a naive viewer.  I suppose the distance that is analogous for categorical data (in that it would be the most immediately intuitive) would be simple matching.  However, I am open to discussions of other distances if that leads to a solution or just an interesting discussion.

Comment: I wonder if we have anything like clusters in categorical data *at all*. It's not as if the variance between clusters will be bigger than within clusters, or can talk about a density difference between clusters. So if the clostest match are frequent itemsets, then variables must be related for clusters to form.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, that's interesting.  Why not develop that into an answer?  BTW, I can image clusters actually existing (eg, in latent continuous variables that give rise to differing probabilities for various levels of nominal variables), but I suspect that isn't what you meant.

Comment: You can transform a categorical distribution to a vector whose components are the normalized frequencies. Then the Euclidean metric can be applied. It's not the only option though:http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/02_spaces_fcns.pdf and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider the clear-cluster case with uncorrelated scale variables - such as the top-right picture in the question. And categorize its data.

[image]

We subdivided the scale range of both variables X and Y into 3 bins which now onward we treat as categorical labels. Moreover, we'll declare them nominal, not ordinal, because the question asked is implicitly and primarily about qualitative data. The spots' size is the frequency in a frequency cross-table cell; all cases in the same cell are considered identical.

Intuitively and most generally, "clusters" are defined as clots of data points separated by sparse regions in the data "space". It was initially with scale data and it remains same impression in the cross-tabulation of the categorized data. X and Y now categorical, but they still look uncorrelated: chi-square association is very near to zero. And clusters are there.

But recall we're dealing with nominal categories which order in the table is arbitrary. We may reorder whole rows and/or columns as we like, without affecting the observed chi-square value. Do reordering...

[image]

...to meet that clusters just dissapeared. The four cells, a1, a3, c1 and c3, could be united in a single cluster. So no, we really *don't* have any clusters in the categorical data.

Cases of cells a1 and c3 (or likewise of a3 and c1) are complete-dissimilar: they don't share same attribures. To induce clusters in our data - a1 and c3 to form the clusters - we have to empty, to some great extent, confounding cells a3 and c1, by dropping these cases from the dataset.

[image]

Now clusters do exist. But at the same time we lost uncorrelatedness. The **diagonal structure** showing up in the table signals that chi-square statistic got far from zero.

Pity. Let us attempt to preserve uncorrelatedness and more or less clear clusters at the same time. We may decide to sufficiently empty just cell a3, for example, and then to consider a1+c1 as a cluster which opposes cluster c3:

[image]

That operation didn't bring Chi-square any far from zero...

```
[Indeed, table such as for example
 6   6   1
 6   6   1
 1   1   0
retains about the same very low chi-square association after
dividing 2nd column by 3 and multiplying 2nd row by 3, which gives
 6   2   1
18   6   3
 1  1/3  0
Cell (1,2) got thrice lower frequency. We had, however, to upheave
cell (2,1) frequency thrice, to keep Chi-sq almost as before.]
```

...but the situation with clusters is confused. Cluster a1+c1 contains cases that partly identical, partly half-dissimilar. That a cluster is relatively low-homogeneous is itself not a preclusion for a clear-cluster structure in a dataset. However, the problem with our, categorical data is that cluster a1+c1 is in no way *better* than cluster c1+c3, its symmetric analogue. That means that the cluster solution is *unstable* - it will depend on the case order in the dataset. An unstable solution, even it is relatively "clear-clustered", is a bad solution, unreliable.

The only way to overcome the problem and to make solution both clear and stable will be to untie cell c3 from cell c1 by moving its data below to cell b3 (or to b2).

[image]

So we have clear clusters a1+c1 vs b3. But look, here again the diagonal pattern shows up - and chi-square of the table bounds high above zero.

**Conclusion**. It is impossible to have two chi-square-unassociated nominal variables and good clusters of the data cases simultaneously. Clear & stable clusters imply inducing variable association.

It is also clear that if the association is present - i.e. diagonal pattern exists or achievable by reordering - then clusters must exist. This is because the nature of categorical data ("all or nothing") doesn't permit half tones and borderline conditions, therefore picture like bottom-left in the OP's question can't emerge with categorical, nominal data.

I surmise that as we get more and more nominal variables (instead of just two) which are *bivariately* chi-square unrelated, we come closer to the possibility to have clusters. But zero multivariate chi-square, I expect still will be incompatible with clusters. That yet has to be shown (not by me or not this time).

---

Finally, a remark on @Bey's (aka user75138) answer which I partly supported. I've commented it with my agreement on that one has first to decide on the distance metric and the association measure before he can put the question "is variable association independent from case clusters?". This is because no universal association measure exist, nor universal *statistical* definition of clusters. I would further add, he must also decide on the clustering technique. Various methods of clustering differently define what are "clusters" they are after. So, the whole statement might be true.

That said, the weakness of such a dictum is that it's too broad. One should attempt to show concretely, whether and where a choice on distance metric / association measure / cluster method opens room to reconcile uncorrelatedness with clusteredness, for nominal data. He would keep in mind, particular, that not all the many proximity coefficients for binary data make sense with nominal data, since for nominal data, "both cases lack this attribute" can never be the ground for their similarity.

---

**Update**, reporting my simulations findings.

Repearedly, 2- or 3-variable nominal data were randomly generated, with the number of categories in a variable varying from 3 to 5, and the total sample size varying from 300 to 600. Bivariate chi-square association was very low in all the generated datasets (Cramer's V almost never above $.1$). Also, for 3-variable data 3-way chi-square association (main effects multinomial model), Pearson and Log-likelihood, was low and never significant.

Two methods of cluster analysis were used to cluster cases in each of the generated datasets - Hierarchical clustering ([complete](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/195446/3277) method, [Dice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/55798/3277) similarity measure), and [TwoStep](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/81603/3277) clustering (basing on log-likelihood distance). Then a range of cluster solutions (varying by the number of clusters in a solution) from each analysis was checked by some [internal clustering criterions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/195481/3277) (silhouette statistic, point-biserial $r$, AIC & BIC) in search of a relatively "good" solution, indicating the presence of clear clusters. A liked solution was then tested for stability by means of permuting case order in the dataset and redoing the clustering on it.

*Findings generally support* reasoning displayed above within the answer. There was never *very* clear clusters (such as might occure if the chi-square association be strong). And the results of the different clustering criterions often contradicted each other (which isn't very likely to expect when clusters are really clear).

Sometimes hierarchical clustering would offer a k-cluster solution that is somewhat good, as observed via a clustering criterion plot; however, testing it for stability will fail to show it is stable. For example, this 3-variable `4x4x3` data

```
   V1  V2  V3   Count
    1   1   1   21
            2   24
            3   1
        2   1   22
            2   26
            3   1
        3   1   1
            2   1
            3   1
        4   1   17
            2   20
            3   1
    2   1   1   10
            2   12
            3   1
        2   1   10
            2   12
            3   1
        3   1   1
            2   1
            3   1
        4   1   8
            2   9
            3   1
    3   1   1   24
            2   28
            3   1
        2   1   25
            2   30
            3   1
        3   1   1
            2   1
            3   1
        4   1   19
            2   23
            3   1
    4   1   1   24
            2   28
            3   1
        2   1   26
            2   30
            3   1
        3   1   1
            2   1
            3   1
        4   1   19
            2   23
            3   1
```

when clustered by the complete linkage hiearchical method, Dice similarity, seem to be split - quite reasonably - into 9 clusters - in this case in agreement among the three internal validity judges:

[image]

But the solution is not stable, as seen from the noncomplete sparsity of the confusion matrix of the original solution against the permuted (case-reordered) solution:

[image]

If the solution had been stable (as it would likely be had we continuous data) we would have chosen the 9-cluster solution as sufficiently persuasive one.

Clustering based on log-likelihood distance (as opposed to Dice similarity) may give stable and "not bad" (internally quite valid) solutions. But that is *because* the distance, at least as it is in TwoStep cluster of SPSS, encourage and foster high-populated clusters and neglect low-populated ones. It does not demand clusters with very low frequency inside to be dense inside (that seem to be the "policy" of TwoStep cluster analysis, which was designed specially for big data and to give few clusters; so small clusters are seen as if outliers). For example, these 2-variable data

[image]

would be combined by TwoStep into 5 clusters as shown, stably, and the 5-cluster solution is not at all bad as judged by some clustering criterions. Because the four populated clusters are very dense inside (actually, all cases identical), and only one, fifth cluster, which includes few cases, is extremely entropy'ed. So apparent actually is 12-cluster solution, not 5-cluster, but 12 is the total number of cells in the frequency table, which, as a "cluster solution" is trivial and uninteresting.

Comment: +1, this is what I suspected. The *pairwise* unassociated vs multivariate unassociated is an interesting point. Considering this issue more broadly, does this imply that there isn't really any point in trying to cluster purely nominal data? Ie, should we just always analyze the variables if we don't have any continuous data?

Comment: @gung, don't you know the maxim that correlation between _variables_ is the other side of the coin of _cases'_ polarization ("diagolness")? This is true, as maxim, also for continuous data. But for continuous, polarization may not imply clusters. For categorical, it appears it implies. Due to discrete nature. So probably yes, if categorical variables correlate, there are clusters to find. But you have to _do_ clustering in order to get the clusters the better way. That's my tentative opinion for your great question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. Maybe I'll ask about it later.  This is good information to chew on for now, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) -- the Hamming distance between two strings of equal length is the number of positions at which the corresponding symbols are different. From this definition it seems obvious that we can produce data for which we have clusters based on the Hamming distance but no correlations between the variables.

An example follows using Mathematica.

Create some categorical data (3 symbols long sequences of uniform random sampling of 4 characters):

```
chs = CharacterRange["a", "d"];
words = StringJoin @@@ Union[Table[RandomChoice[chs, 3], 40]];
Length[words]
words

(* 29 *)

(* {"aac", "aad", "abb", "aca", "acb", "acd", "adb", "adc", "baa", "bab", "bac", "bad", "bcc", "bcd", "caa", "cab", "cac", "cad", "cbb", "ccb", "cda", "cdb", "dab", "dba", "dbb", "dbd", "dca", "dcc", "dcd"} *)
```

Use mosaic plots for the relationship between the variables (conditional probabilities for pairs of values from different columns):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MosaicPlot.m"]
wordSeqs = Characters /@ words;
opts = {ColorRules -> {2 -> ColorData[7, "ColorList"]}, ImageSize -> 400};
Grid[{{MosaicPlot[wordSeqs[[All, {1, 2}]], 
    "ColumnNames" -> {"column 1", "column 2"}, opts],
   MosaicPlot[wordSeqs[[All, {2, 3}]], 
    "ColumnNames" -> {"column 2", "column 3"}, opts],
   MosaicPlot[wordSeqs[[All, {1, 3}]], 
    "ColumnNames" -> {"column 1", "column 3"}, opts]}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

We can see that there is no correlation.

Find clusters:

```
cls = FindClusters[words, 3, DistanceFunction -> HammingDistance]

(* {{"aac", "aad", "adc", "bac"}, {"abb", "acb", "adb", "baa", "bab", "bad", 
  "caa", "cab", "cac", "cad", "cbb", "ccb", "cda", "cdb", "dab", 
  "dbb"}, {"aca", "acd", "bcc", "bcd", "dba", "dbd", "dca", "dcc", "dcd"}} *)
```

If we replace every character with an integer we can see from this plot how the clusters are formed with Hamming distance:

```
esrules = Thread[chs -> Range[Length[chs]]]; gr1 = 
 ListPointPlot3D[Characters[cls] /. esrules, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Left, Back}];
gr2 = Graphics3D[
   Map[Text[#, Characters[#] /. esrules, {1, 1}] &, Flatten[cls]]];
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]

### Further clustering

Let us make a graph by connecting the words for which the Hamming distance is 1:

```
mat = Clip[Outer[HammingDistance, words, words], {0, 1}, {0, 0}];
nngr = AdjacencyGraph[mat, 
  VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[Length[words]] -> words]]
```

[image]

Now let us find the community clusters:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[nngr]
```

[image]

Compare the graph clusters with the one found with `FindClusters` (which was forced to find 3). We can see "bac" is highly central, and "aad" can belong to the green cluster, which corresponds to cluster 1 in 3D plot.

#### Graph data

Here is the edge list of `nngr`:

```
{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 8, 1 <-> 11, 1 <-> 17, 2 <-> 6, 2 <-> 12, 2 <-> 18, 
 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 7, 3 <-> 19, 3 <-> 25, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 4 <-> 27, 
 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 7, 5 <-> 20, 6 <-> 14, 6 <-> 29, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 22, 
 9 <-> 10, 9 <-> 11, 9 <-> 12, 9 <-> 15, 10 <-> 11, 10 <-> 12, 
 10 <-> 16, 10 <-> 23, 11 <-> 12, 11 <-> 13, 11 <-> 17, 12 <-> 14, 
 12 <-> 18, 13 <-> 14, 13 <-> 28, 14 <-> 29, 15 <-> 16, 15 <-> 17, 
 15 <-> 18, 15 <-> 21, 16 <-> 17, 16 <-> 18, 16 <-> 19, 16 <-> 20, 
 16 <-> 22, 16 <-> 23, 17 <-> 18, 19 <-> 20, 19 <-> 22, 19 <-> 25, 
 20 <-> 22, 21 <-> 22, 23 <-> 25, 24 <-> 25, 24 <-> 26, 24 <-> 27, 
 25 <-> 26, 26 <-> 29, 27 <-> 28, 27 <-> 29, 28 <-> 29}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just a pair of remarks: What language is the code? (which is not annotated, besides). How do you define `relationship between the variables (correlation)`?

Comment: This is interesting. Unfortunately, I don't know Mathematica (& am less familiar with edit distance), so I need to play with this to be sure I understand it. I haven't had a chance yet, but I intend to soon.

Comment: @gung I was thinking to do it in R but I thought that the crucial part is the 3D plot and rotating it in the right angle(s) to get an insight of the clusters formation. Good question, by the way!

Comment: So you have "clusters" here. But are they meaningful? Are they better than other clusters? From the plot, I'd say cluster 1 is pretty random. So why is that a cluster?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I should have labeled the points with the corresponding words -- I updated my answer with such a plot. From [that plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vzTFO.png) it should be obvious that cluster 1 is a very strong one from the Hamming distance perspective -- each point has at least one neighbor with distance one. Also, I forced `FindClusters` to find three clusters, this partially explains what we see. I could have used another, more illustrative clustering algorithm for this example.

Comment: Why is `adc` in cluster 1, and not in cluster 2 (which contains `adb`?) I realize now that the coordinates are meaningless, and the 4 could be a 0, too. But you see: it's rather arbitrary which clister contains `adc`, `adb` etc.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse The coordinates are not "meaningless" - the mapping from character to integer is obvious. I will show you a better layout of the clusters tomorrow, hopefully your questions I that regard will be satisfied...

Comment: They are meaningless/misleading in the sense that the difference of 4 to 1 is 1.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse The mapping from the Hamming distance space to the Euclidean space can be confusing. See my update, I made a distance graph and a related clustering. As I mentioned in my previous comment, the community graph should give you enough clarity about the clusters.

Comment: Can you post the matrix of Hamming distances? Also, what is the algorithm of clustering you used? How does it work?

Comment: I think this is interesting. I was able to replicate your clustering using PAM & the edit distances for your data. I find that I share @Anony-Mousse's concerns, though. I think the crux of it is that there appear to be no actual clusters in the data generating process. These are just purely random letter combinations. It happens that the edit distances between them yield clusters, but that seems to be entirely happenstance.

Comment: Random uniform (!) generated data clearly should not have clusters. The "community" plot is *misleading* because it does not preserve distances. The graph with 1-distance emphasizes these problems. It also shows another such example, `cda`. Sorry, I'm not "buying" these "clusters". The data is uniform, it is supposed to *not* have clusters.

Comment: [Multidimensional Scaling of the data using Hamming distance](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tQrqM.png) (there are some nonintuitively placed objects here though). No clusters. In your "community plot", **can you explain `cab`**? The red one, where you can't read the label. It connects to half the violet cluster (`cbb`, `ccb`, `cdb`)? The `c_b` form one of three 4-clique in this graph, the strongest structures there. `ca_` and `ba_` being the other two.

Comment: @ttnphns I added the edge list of the graph to the answer; the graph adjacency matrix is too big. I will post R code that parallels the one in Mathematica. (Seems to be preferred...)

Answer (score 4):

@ttnphns' point about *pairwise* vs *multivariate* association is well taken. Related to that is the old saw about the importance of demonstrating association with simple metrics before leaping into a multivariate framework. In other words, if simple pairwise measures of association show no relationship then it becomes increasingly unlikely that multivariate relationships will show anything either. I say "increasingly unlikely" because of a reluctance to use the word "impossible." In addition, I am agnostic as to the metric employed whether it be a monotonic Spearman correlations for ordinal data, Somer's *D*, Kendall's *Tau*, polychoric correlation, the Reshef's MIC, Szelkey's distance correlation, whatever. The choice of metric is not important in this discussion.

The original work done on finding latent structure in categorical information dates back to the early 50s and Paul Lazersfeld, the Columbia sociologist. Essentially, he invented a class of latent variable models that has seen extensive development and modification since. First, with the 60s work of James Coleman, the U of C political economist, on latent voter election propensities, followed by the contributions of the late Clifford Clogg, also a sociologist, whose MELISSA software was the first publicly available latent class freeware.

In the 80s, latent class models were extended from purely categorical information to finite mixture models with development of tools such as Latent Gold from Statistical Innovations. In addition, Bill Dillon, a marketing scientist, developed a Gauss program for fitting latent discriminant finite mixture models. The literature on this approach to fitting mixtures of categorical and continuous information is actually quite extensive. It's just not as well known outside of the fields where it has been most widely applied, e.g., marketing science where these models are used for consumer segmentation and clustering.

However, these finite mixture model approaches to latent clustering and contingency table analysis are considered old school in today's world of massive data. The state-of-the-art in finding association among a huge set of contingency tables are the decompositions available from deploying tensor models such as those developed by David Dunson and other Bayesians at Duke. Here is the abstract from one of their papers as well as a link:

> Contingency table analysis routinely relies on log linear models, with
>   latent structure analysis providing a common alternative. Latent
>   structure models lead to a low rank tensor factorization of the
>   probability mass function for multivariate categorical data, while log
>   linear models achieve dimensionality reduction through sparsity.
>   Little is known about the relationship between these notions of
>   dimensionality reduction in the two paradigms. We derive several
>   results relating the support of a log-linear model to the nonnegative
>   rank of the associated probability tensor. Motivated by these
>   findings, we propose a new collapsed Tucker class of tensor
>   decompositions, which bridge existing PARAFAC and Tucker
>   decompositions, providing a more flexible framework for parsimoniously
>   characterizing multivariate categorical data. Taking a Bayesian
>   approach to inference, we illustrate advantages of the new
>   decompositions in simulations and an application to functional
>   disability data.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.0396.pdf

Comment: This is interesting information. I'm not as clear on how it connects to the question.

Comment: gung Given the wide ranging discussion and the fundamental questions raised as to whether clusters of categorical data "even exist," your lack of clarity as to the relevance of my contribution is puzzling. In my view, the information provided illuminates areas of methodology and knowledge discovery previously ignored. May I also point out my initial observation -- explicitly addressed to the OPs question -- regarding the leap from pairwise to multivariate association being highly unlikely in the absence of association at the simpler level.

Comment: I didn't mean any offense, @DJohnson. I am (somewhat) familiar w/ latent models for clustering categorical data (ie, latent class analysis). I alluded to it in my [comment](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218604/219419?noredirect=1#comment413758_218604) above. I was not as familiar w/ the history, researchers, & software. That is interesting. I don't quite see how it answers the question of whether there can be detectable clusters in nominal data where the variables don't show any association. If that's what you're getting at, an example would be helpful. Can you provide one?

Comment: @gung  Of course not and none taken.

Answer (score 3):

As I'm sure you know, correlation is a measure of the linear relationship between two variables, not how close the points are to each other. This explains the top four figures.

Of course, you could also create similar graphs for discrete, real-valued data as well.

The problem with more abstract distributions, such as $X \in \{A,B,C,D\}$ is that, unlike variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, we cannot assume that the image of a categorical random variable forms a *metric space*. We get this automatically when $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, but not so when we have $X$ taking values on some arbitrary set.

You'd need to define a metric for the categorical space before you can really even talk about clustering in the geometric sense.

Comment: I would support this answer and would reformulate it, if both @gung and Bey allow, in intuitive terms. Clustered data are defined by "small distances in cluster but long distances between clusters". On his pictures, the OP selected, implicitly, _euclidean_ distance to illustrate this idea of clusteredness. He also selected the notion of Pearson correlation or something similar to it - to illustrate the idea of association between variables. These are two particular/arbitrary choices among many alternatives.

Comment: (cont.)  I might even imagine that there could be chosen such distance measure and such association measure where "case clusteredness" conception and "variable associations" conception are not orthogonal. And now, for categorical data. _Before_ one can check & show whether the two conceptions can be independent or are related he must select a specific distance measure for categorical data points and a specific association measure for categorical variables. There's many alternatives to select from! And the answer will depend.

Comment: @ttnphns (+1) I like how you framed the two main choices: distance and  association metrics. Not sure what about my explanation was not intuitive though...you can't define clusters without a notion of distance.

Comment: @ttnphns, I think it's up to Bey. Why don't you turn some of your ideas into your own answer? I'd be interested in the idea that the "case clusteredness" & "variable associations" become non-orthogonal for the continuous data given some choices. Bey & ttnphns, I have added some clarifications to the question regarding distance & association measures, but you should feel free to go in a different direction, if you prefer. Let me know if it needs more. My preference is that the question remain as 'loose' as possible to give answerers the flexibility to go in a different direction.

Comment: @ttnphns, why did you delete your answer? I really haven't had much time to spend here (unfortunately), but it looked interesting.

Comment: @ttnphns, it is. I hope you'll return to it at some point.

Comment: @gung, I ultimately think it is impossible to have zero or low chi-sq association and anyhow clear clusters at the same time (so I deleted my answer). Obviously, clear clusters with nominal variables mean that in the frequency `rXc` cross-table there must exist (or be achievable via row or column reordering) a diagonal structure in the table formed by some high-frequency cells. That is incompatible with the absence of chi-square association.

Comment: @ttnphns if we allow arbitrary row-column reorderings of a contingency matrix then we can find clusters in almost any dataset, since you can search the space of row-column swaps to maximize the chi-square statistic. This will induce an arbitrary metric in the space  of categorical outcomes. Such clusters will likely be spurious.

Comment: @ttnphns, why not make *that* an answer.

Comment: @gung At this point, I'm not sure what else to add to my answer. All the answers on this page start by constructing or implicitly inducing a concept of distance. Once you have that, you can then specify an appropriate association measure and construct an example like your cases in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with pearson correlation. In essence, you are transforming an abstract categorical space to one with some minimal geometric properties. To reiterate: without a concept of distance, no clustering is possible. That's the basic idea.

Comment: I was familiar with that before I asked the question, @Bey. I left the question somewhat ambiguous at first to give answerers the freedom to move in a direction I hadn't thought of (eg, maybe it would work with Hamming distances--something that hadn't occurred to me). If you need something more concrete, simple matching and chi-squared is what I had in mind, although I didn't mention them explicitly at first.

Comment: @gung ah, thanks for the clarification. I was focused on your basic question about whether categorical clustering without association was possible, in principle, given your statement *"Is it even possible to have clusters in purely categorical data without the variables being related as well?"*... Which it of course is for a given notion of distance and association.

Comment: @Bey, there are, of course, many other possible distance and association measures for categorical data, so you're free to suggest something esoteric that makes it work.