# Jaccard distance vs Levenshtein distance for fuzzy matching

Tags: r, text-mining, similarities, distance-functions, jaccard-similarity

My data is similar to the following data, but far bigger and more complex.

```
Apple
Banana
Those fruits
Tomato 
Cocumber
These vegetables
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
Those fruits
These vegetables
```

Using the `agrep/agrepl` function in `R` I received a first result. However `agrep` and `agrepl` use the Levenshtein distance as default. An alternative would be the Jaccard distance.

Jaccard distance vs Levenshtein distance: Which distance is better for fuzzy matching?

There is already a similar question:
[Properties of Levenshtein, N-Gram, cosine and Jaccard distance coefficients - in sentence matching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219243/properties-of-levenshtein-n-gram-cosine-and-jaccard-distance-coefficients-in). However I would like to know which distance works best for **Fuzzy matching**.

Extra credits: Are other distance measure (e.g. N-Gram, Cosine, Geometric, Manhattan) also useful for **Fuzzy matching**? Implementations in `R` are also welcome.

Comment: If your data are far bigger, something like LSH might be faster and also preserve the "fuzzy" property in a very specific sense. Some LSH schemes are easily demonstrated to be probabilistic Jaccard similarity.

Comment: in R you have the [stringdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/) package. You might to check that one out.