# Dice coefficient: what is the effect of a smoothing factor?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, accuracy, precision

I've come across code to calculate a Dice coefficient in imaging segmentation, in which a "smoothing factor" was added to the formula, as below (pseudo-code):

```
sf = 1    
Dice = [2 (A * B) + sf] / [(A + B) + sf]
```

What would be the purpose of this and its effect on the output of Dice coefficient?

Comment: Probably sf insures against zero denominator? But the thing with your question is that Dice, as I know, has different formula from yours (see e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55802/3277 ).

Comment: that's interesting, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sørensen-Dice_coefficient it seems `2` should be multiplied by the sum of numerator (intersection), do you agree?