# How does the Gower distance calculate the difference between binary variables'?

Tags: clustering, distance, mixed-type-data, gower-similarity

I have 17 numeric and 5 binary (0-1) variables, with 73 samples in my dataset. I need to run a cluster analysis. I know that the Gower distance is a good metric for datasets with mixed variables. However, I couldn't understand how the Gower distance calculates the difference between **binary variables**. It seems to me that it is not different from Euclidean distance.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Are you simply asking 'how does the Gower distance calculate the difference between binary variables'? What does "there is no difference than Euclidean" mean?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I ask how Gower calculate the difference between binary variables. I mean, I couldn't understand the differences btw. Euclidean and Gower for binary variable.

Comment: Have you searched this site for `Gower`? http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/3277

Comment: Yes I did. Euclidean distance is 0, if both samples have same value, 1 if not. What about Gower?

Comment: @EmrahBilgiç, Gower metric is similarity, _not_ distance. It becomes "distance" when is subtracted from 1. Read under the link above how it processes binary data.

Comment: I read the details of daisy function; "The contribution d(ij,k) of a nominal or binary variable to the total dissimilarity is 0 if both values are equal, 1 otherwise." This is not different from what Euclidean does for binary variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about binary attributes that have the values "m" and "f", for "male" and "female"?

You do realize that for a dicotomous variable *all* you can get out is "same" or "different"? The key point difference between distances is not if the value is 1 or 0; but how multiple variables are combined.

Answer (score 5):

Gower distance uses Manhattan for calculating distance between continuous datapoints and Dice for calculating distance between categorical datapoints