# Non-parametric Clustering for mixed-type data

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, spss

Currently I am studying Cluster Analysis where I am going through the TwoStep clustering method found in SPSS (it is a futher developed BIRCH method).

Does anyone know what can be used as an alternative to the twostep clustering when the data do not follow its assumptions: the twostep clustering assumes the continuous variables are independent normally distributed and for categorical variables assumes independent multinomially distributed. Is there a non parametric algorithm that caters both for categorical and continuous data at the same time?

Comment: TwoStep cluster procedure was designed for the task to cope with huge number of objects. For up to about a thousand or so objects, hierarchical cluster is more flexible and superior to it (you may use Gower similarity for mixed type data).

Comment: TwoStep claims it is fairly robust to violations of its assumptions. And it is impossible, I think, to invent a nonparametric, distribution free clustering method for any big data because we can "speed up" a process only at expence of making assumptions about data.

Comment: @ttphns - I agree with you that two TwoStep clustering is designed to cope with large data set but when using the Log likelihood distance it is assumed that the data is normally distributed for continuous variable and multinomial distributed for categorical variables. So it makes assumptions on the data, I am asking if there is some other method which is distribution free.

Comment: I understood you. I actually answered - I hope so - your question. Use Hierarchical (say, avarage or complete linkage) with Gower. If you need a method for huge number of objects - you have to "pay" by making assumptions. TwoStep is a way to go (it is not a bad method, yet not quite good - in my experience). Btw, the uncorrelatedness and normality assumption is _within_ each cluster, not for the whole data cloud, hope you understand.

Comment: @ttnphns - I understood you much better now...thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: ttnphns - Regarding the Gower distance measure can be use as a non parametric distance measure cause in the following link it is saying that Gower is sensitive to non normality?http://dpmartin42.github.io/blogposts/r/cluster-mixed-types

Comment: So what? It is sensitive to it. Euclidean distance will be sensitive too.  I wonder why they dropped that point into a passage actually borrowed from [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/3277) here. Gower similarity coefficient is not model based, it has no distributional assumptions and can be used with any data distribution. That doesn't mean that it is _robust_ or insensitive to violations of normality or to outliers in continuous variables. I would not label it either "parametric" or "nonparametric", these words are simply irrelevant here.

Comment: @ttnphns - Thank you this is much clear now I just wanted to make sure that what I am writing and understanding is correct. Thanks once again :)