# Options for Clustering Analysis with Numeric & Nominal Data with Gower Distance

Tags: r, python, clustering, gower-similarity

I am working through some cluster analysis (trying to propose new item types for various clusters). I have data that has both numeric and nominal features. After creating dummy variables for all categorical data I am looking at a dataset of dimensions (72k x 100).

I have read things about Gower's distance and see where it may be applicable here but I am curious if my data is too high dimensional? One of my nominal features that I have dummified has around 40 levels (I have basically done a ranking since the original variable has about 900 levels but the top 40 levels consist of about 89% of the total counts for that variable so the rest of those levels I have just grouped into an 'other' category.

I am open to using R or Python (currently most of my processing is in python) and am familiar with the `gower` package in Python. However, when creating the distance matrix I have to tell `gower.gower_matrix()` (see example here https://www.thinkdatascience.com/post/2019-12-16-introducing-python-package-gower/) which features are categorical. Since my data are already in dummy form, do I treat my binary 0s and 1s in my many columns as categorical columns?

Maybe there are other ways around this or R is simpler but I'm trying to devise a good way at handling my dataset with many dummy variables which originated from mixed data types.

Github code for Gower package in python: https://github.com/wwwjk366/gower/blob/master/gower/gower_dist.py

Here is some example code:

```
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'lag': [1,2,0,0,10],
                                 'age': [44, 50, 38, 40, 60],
                                 'zone_central':[0,0,0,1,0],
                                 'zone_east':[0,1,1,0,1],
                                 'zone_unknown':[0,0,1,0,0],
                                 'zone_west':[1,0,0,0,0]})
print(df.head(20))

# set dummy variables as strings so they aren't interpreted as numeric in the gower package
df.iloc[:,2:6] = df.iloc[:,2:6].apply(str)
print(df.dtypes)

   lag  age  zone_central  zone_east  zone_unknown  zone_west
0    1   44             0          0             0          1
1    2   50             0          1             0          0
2    0   38             0          1             1          0
3    0   40             1          0             0          0
4   10   60             0          1             0          0
lag              int64
age              int64
zone_central    object
zone_east       object
zone_unknown    object
zone_west       object
dtype: object
```

Using the `gower` package with the last 4 variables set as `True` since they are dummy variables and I don't want to compute euclidean distance between them (the whole point of using Gower)

```
gower.gower_matrix(df, cat_features=[False,False,True,True,True,True])
array([[0.        , 0.22878788, 0.22878788, 0.21363637, 0.4378788 ],
       [0.22878788, 0.        , 0.12424242, 0.10909091, 0.2090909 ],
       [0.22878788, 0.12424242, 0.        , 0.01515151, 0.33333334],
       [0.21363637, 0.10909091, 0.01515151, 0.        , 0.3181818 ],
       [0.4378788 , 0.2090909 , 0.33333334, 0.3181818 , 0.        ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Using the default with `cat_features` unspecified which infers datatypes from inputs

```
gower.gower_matrix(df)
array([[0.        , 0.22878788, 0.22878788, 0.21363637, 0.4378788 ],
       [0.22878788, 0.        , 0.12424242, 0.10909091, 0.2090909 ],
       [0.22878788, 0.12424242, 0.        , 0.01515151, 0.33333334],
       [0.21363637, 0.10909091, 0.01515151, 0.        , 0.3181818 ],
       [0.4378788 , 0.2090909 , 0.33333334, 0.3181818 , 0.        ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

I still get the same results (I assume the Gower function infers the last 4 columns are categorical since I have their dtypes set as 'object' from pandas.

Comment: `Since my data are already in dummy form`. I've not worked with the Gower functions in R or Python, but I'm pretty sure they don't need or expect you to recode your categorical features into sets of dummies. You categorical features to input should be your original nominal ones.

Comment: Read about Gower measure here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/3277