# Clustering method for Gower distances

Tags: r, clustering, distance, gower-similarity

I am having a mixed data type and I want to implement cluster my data set into 3 clusters. Because I have mixed data I have to compute gower distance as part of a distance matrix.Now that I have this gower distance matrix, what are the different algorithms I can use with distance matrix as an input in R? Please let me know.

Thank you.

Regards,
Anil

Comment: Please start with reading here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/3277.

Comment: Several methods of grouping assume that objects can be described by a matrix containing a measure of similarity (distance) between them. Once you have this matrix, you can use Pam.

Comment: A list of algorithms that can be used for clustering is far too broad to be answered in this format. Can you be specific about what would make an algorithm a good candidate for your particular use-case?